# Setting Up WordPress MS Locally with Port 8888 with XAMPP

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, xampp, httpd.conf, hosts-file

I have installed XAMPP and edited the httpd.conf file because my port 80 is busy.
So I have the following:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:8888
Servername localhost:8888
```

Everything works fine until I try to install WordPress 3.0.5 MS because it will not accept ports in the name.

So I have tried to add .htaccess file to my htdocs that contains:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^:8888/(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

But that did not work.

So I have tried to create Virtual Hosts in httpd.conf adding the following at the bottom:

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/www/wp.dev">
  Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/">
  Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>


NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8888
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8888>
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
   ServerName localhost2
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8888>
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/www/wp.dev"
   ServerName wp.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

And then I added the following to my hosts file ([Help](http://www.fpweb.net/support/managed-hosting/hostfile-editing-support.asp)):

```
127.0.0.1:8888       localhost2
127.0.0.1:8888       wp.dev
```

And that hasn't worked. I cannot use port 80 as an option, so I need to figure this out. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately WordPress MS requires port 80 to work. You can check the requirements in [this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WPMU#WordPress_Settings_Requirements)

If using that port in your local machine is not an option for you, what you could consider is to work with a Virtual Machine. ([This is the link](http://bitnami.org/stack/wordpress#virtualMachine) to the BitNami WordPress virtual appliance in case you want to try it.)